# Learn through comments: Is this a sin?

Tags: discussion

Recently I have asked the question *[How can I use a custom control class that inherits from a built-in control on my main form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5692419/how-can-i-use-a-custom-control-class-that-inherits-from-a-built-in-control-on-my)*, and I am having a good response from our great community, but there is a comment issued by Sanjeevakumar Hiremath as below:

> @mahesh, pick up a book on .Net Windows Forms and try reading these steps instead of leaving comment on every possible steps.

I want to ask our community and moderator too. That learning through comments: Is this a sin over there?

I am waiting for an answer for my question. Which is very useful in the second session for me. I want to know if somebody wants to learn by comments is wrong or right or he/she should stop to leave comments for further inquiry?

Comment: Your focus on comments is avoiding the real issue of your questions consistently being of poor quality.

Answer (score 15):

Sanjeevakumar is saying that you're asking a bunch of really simple questions, and not only are they simple, but they are very low quality. It doesn't appear that you're spending very much time or putting very much effort into writing your questions.

His comment says that you'll have a lot better luck if you get a book that teaches you the basics of .NET Windows Forms programming, rather than trying to ask questions about each step. This is probably true; it's hard to really learn something well without a solid background, and it's hard to get this type of background from individual questions on a Q&A site.

Because of the volume of questions we get each day on Stack Overflow, we try very hard to deter users from contributing low-quality content. There are even automatic filters that kick in if it looks like you're one of those people, and your IP address can be permanently banned. However, at this point, your account has only been [*temporarily suspended* by a moderator](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/). This is not permanent. Instead, the hope is that you'll learn that you need to take time to ask better questions, and become a participating member of the community once again.

You can learn more about temporary and permanent account bans from the answer to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-from-this), as well as see some tips about how to ask better quality questions.

To answer the question you actually asked here, no there is absolutely nothing wrong with learning through comments. We all do that. I myself learn new things all the time through comments. The problem is the **quantity**, along with the fact that you haven't shown any attempt to improve the quality of your questions over time: you can't learn *everything* through comments.

Comment: As an aside: this user is currently *suspended*, which is a manual action of a moderator. The automatic filtering that I am aware of, is permanent (non-expiring) until the user manages to increase their reputation by posting good quality answers (or by editing existing posts and somehow get upvotes for that).

Comment: As for learning through comments: what bothers me with some users' comments is that they seem to be about *different* topics, not really related to the question that was asked. Using comments in that way, kind of turns the commenting into a forum. (I am not saying that this specific user also is doing this; haven't really checked.)

Comment: @Arjan: Yeah, I see a *lot* of that. I try to be as detailed and helpful as possible in my answers, and users appreciate that. The inevitable consequence is that they want me to explain the next steps to them in comments, as well. There's a very thin line between what is simple an "extension" of my answer, and what qualifies as an entirely new question. I've recently decided that I've been too nice in answering, and have started telling people to ask a new question, instead.

Answer (score 7):

See

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

The most common suspension reason these days, by far, is this:

> #### No effort to learn and improve over time
>
> - This user does not put reasonable effort into the questions they ask of the community.
> - There is little or no evidence of this user learning over time, either in the topic itself  or in the community norms on the site.
> - This user intentionally spams the site with the same question or very similar questions, over and over.
> - The user never gives anything back to the community, but only takes.

So to answer your question: you haven't shown sufficient evidence to us that you *are* learning.

Try reading some of the following:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask
- [Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)
- http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555375

Comment: Did you checked my recently question which has upvoted more than 1 or 2

Comment: If i am not trying to learn than How can I obtain upvoted recently more than 1 OR 2?. Please reply it of.

Comment: @mahesh: Looking at your profile, I see a number of upvoted questions. But your newest question has one downvote. It's not sufficient to have a handful of upvoted questions, any more than it is sufficient to have only part of your rent money. Go read the links Jeff gave you, especially the vampires one.